# why pycurl.curl.perform( ) reports an error 'Could not resolve host'?

Tags: pycurl

I import pycurl 7.45.2 successfully and run 'curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.python.org/")       3 dup = curl.duphandle() ----> 4 curl.perform( )', but an error reports that error: 6 'Could not resolve host: www.python.org'. who can help me to look for what reasons are?